# Javascript countdown not repeating every saturday

Tags: javascript, countdown, repeat

my countdown should repeat every saturday at 8pm (gmt+2), however once it hits 8pm, the countdown is stuck on EXPIRED. I don't understand why, does someone recognize the issue?

Appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

```
 function nextSaturday() {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d.getDay());
    if (d.getDay() == 7 && d.getHours() < 20){
      d.setHours(20);
      d.setMinutes(0);
      d.setSeconds(0);
      return d;
    }
    switch (d.getDay()) {
        case 0: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);
            break;
        case 1: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5);
            break;
        case 2: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4);
            break;
        case 3: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 3);
            break;
        case 4: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 2);
            break;
        case 5: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            break;
        case 6: d.setDate(d.getDate() + 0);
            break;
    }
    d.setHours(20);
    d.setMinutes(0);
    d.setSeconds(0);
    return d;
}

var end = nextSaturday();
var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour * 24;
var timer;

function showRemaining() {
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0) {

        clearInterval(timer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "EXPIRED!";

        return;
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Countdown ends in: ";
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML += days + " days ";
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML += hours + " hours ";
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML += minutes + " minutes and ";
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML += seconds + " seconds left";

}
showRemaining();
timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Comment: Your nextSaturday function doesn't handle the condition where today is Saturday and it's after 8pm.  I would suspect you want to add 7 days in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning from this function early.

```
if(d.getDay() == 7 && d.getHours() < 20) { 
  d.setHours(20);
  d.setMinutes(0);
  d.setSeconds(0);
  return d; //right here you are exiting your loop at 8:00 (20 hours)
}
```

`return d;` terminates execution of the function and returns the value of `d`

You have `d` set to this Saturday by this point, you want it to be next Saturday, so you need to add this:

```
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
```

before you return `d`.

**Explanation:**

That if statement above is basically saying, "If it's after 8:00pm on Saturday, set d to 8:00pm on Saturday." Your code will start working again at 12:00am on Sunday when it starts resetting the date to the next Saturday, you simply forgot to increment the date if it happens to be Saturday like you do for all the other days of the week.

**The code exactly as it should be:**

```
if(d.getDay() == 7) { //note: I've also updated this line to account for changes in hours
  d.setHours(20);
  d.setMinutes(0);
  d.setSeconds(0);
    if(d.getHours() >= 20)
      d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
  return d;
}
```

Comment: so what do i have to change?

Comment: Hm i tried the change you suggested, but it keeps saying "expired".

Comment: Add console.log(distance); console.log(end); and console.log(now); right after you calculate distance, and see if you're getting results that you don't expect.

Comment: Hm, now and end seems fine, distance shows -10036006

Comment: Could you send me the full code of what u would change, just to get sure i made it correct

Comment: I've updated my answer, if this is working for you, I'd appreciate it if you'd accept my answer as that would be the courteous thing to do on this site.